# Actualizar datos de un while

Tags: php, javascript, html

Hola buen dia Mi problema es que tengo una tabla de tipo de vehiculos y placas y necesito que actualizen por medio de un boton  solo me funciona con el primer dato mostrado por el while, pero no lo cambia con los demás

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

MI JAVASCRIPT

```
function enviarplacas () {


         var tipo_vehiculo;
         var placa;
        datosactualizados2 = {

        tipo_vehiculo : $ ('.vehiculo').val(),
        placa : $ ('.placa').val(),

        idinsp

        };

    $.post('php/formularioactualiza/editar_placas.php', datosactualizados2, function(rtaactualiza2) {
        console.log(rtaactualiza2)     
          if (rtaactualiza2 == 2){
          alert('se ha actualizado correctamente las placas');
          return;
        } 

        if (rtaactualiza2 == 1){
          alert('No se pudo procesar las placas');
          return;
        }   
    });

    console.log(datosactualizados2)
}
```

MI PHP

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['inspeccionID'])    )  {

  $inspeccion_id = $_POST['inspeccionID'];


include("conexion.php");  

   $result = mysqli_query($mysqli," SELECT * FROM vehiculo_inspeccion WHERE  id_inspeccion = '$inspeccion_id' ");


    if (!empty($result)) { 

        if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {


        while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
               $fila_array['tipo_vehiculo']= $fila['tipo_vehiculo'];
               $fila_array['placa']= $fila['placa'];
               $fila_array['id_veh_ins']= $fila['id_veh_ins'];

echo " 
       <tr>  
         <td colspan='3'><input type='text' class='form-control vehiculo'  disabled='true' id='tipveh".$fila_array['id_veh_ins']."' value='".$fila_array['tipo_vehiculo']."'></td>  
         <td colspan='3'><input type='text' class='form-control placa' disabled='true' id='plc".$fila_array['id_veh_ins']."' value='".$fila_array['placa']."'></td>
         <td colspan='3'><input type='button' class='btn btn-success' id='".$fila_array['id_veh_ins']."' onclick='activarplaca(this)' value='Editar'></button></td>

       </tr>  
    ";      

               } 

        } else { 

echo "
        <tr>  
          <td colspan='6'>  No se encontraron placas en la inspeccion seleccionada. 
          </td> 
        </tr>
     ";     

        }

    } else {

echo "
        <tr>  
          <td colspan='6'> No se encontraron placas en la inspeccion seleccionada. </td> 
        </tr>
    ";


    }
  } else {
    echo "Error";
  }  

?>
```

MI HTML

```
<div>
  <center>
<table  width="55%"  rules="all" border="1" align="center" class="table table-bordered table-hover"> 
  <thead bgcolor="#30c151">                                
   <th colspan="3">Tipo vehiculo</th>
    <th colspan="3">Placa</th>
    <th colspan="3">EDITAR</th>
  </thead>

  <tbody class="datosplaca">

  </tbody>
</table>
 <center>
  <button type="button" id="guardardatos" class="btn btn-info" onclick="enviarplacas()"> ACTUALIZAR PLACAS</button>
</center>
</div>
```

Comment: solo estas opteniendo el varlo del primer campo pon tu html para ver todo el codigo y ayudarte mejor!

Comment: Listo amigo ya pude colocar el html

Comment: Listo ahora si quedo perfecto amigo me habia equivocado un poco

Comment: En primer lugar falta el php que edita, ese que pusiste solo dibuja la tabla, en segundo lugar `$('.placa').val()` solo te regresa el valor de el primer elemento con la clase val que encuentre, necesitas generar el arreglo de vehículos y placas, empieza usando o buscando cómo usar la función `$.each()`

Answer (score 0):

Hola compañero el problema en tu código es que al momento de recibir los datos en tu objeto `"datosactualizados2"` de la forma que lo estas haciendo solo vas a recibir el primer valor de cada de uno de los elementos que contengan esas clases `(".vehiculo",".placa")`. Lo mas sencillo que se me ocurrió de acuerdo a como generas cada linea es agrupar los datos por cada uno de los row generados (tr) es decir `tr[0](input1,input2,button1),"tr[1](input2,input2,button2)"` una vez que tengo esto lo recorres con un `".each"`, luego con el metodo [Find.()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_find.asp)
busco los elementos que necesito y cargo los valores al objeto correctamente. Perdón si soy malo explicando. Saludos

```html
function enviarplacas(){
 var datosactualizados2 = [];
 $(".datosplaca tr").each(function() {
  var inputVeh = $(this).find(".vehiculo");
  var inputPla = $(this).find(".placa");
  var inputBtn = $(this).find(":button");
  datosactualizados2.push( {
    tipo_vehiculo: inputVeh.eq(0).val(),
    placa: inputPla.eq(0).val(),
    idinsp: inputBtn.eq(0).attr('id')
     });
 });
}
// el Resultado seria algo asi 
0: {tipo_vehiculo: "tipo1", placa: "placa1", idinsp: "id1"}
1: {tipo_vehiculo: "tipo2", placa: "placa2", idinsp: "id2"}
```